# Composer package creation issue

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having trouble creating composer package from existing project.
Currently I've a project called `auth`. In there, there is `src` folder, followed by `Authentication` folder (the namespace for the files). I've my codes in this `Authentication` folder.

Now, I've created `composer.json` file in my root directory. The final structure is as follows

- auth(Project root)/

  - src/

    - Authentication/
    - PHP files
- composer.json

My composer.json is

```
{
    "name": "bikasv/auth",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Bikas Vaibhav",
            "email": "******@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Authentication": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try `composer install`, it says `nothing to install or update`.

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**: What I want is to make this very project a composer package so that others can install this using composer. This package itself have no dependency.

I tried with packagist and Github (removed from both places for now though), but when I try to install it using composer, nothing gets installed.

**UPDATE 2**: I've created packagist for this project. You can have a look here http://packagist.org/packages/bikasv/auth

This is not unfailing for me and yes it's proper composer.json which I incorrectly posted earlier.

Comment: See my updated answer. You realise that your actual question is much different to what you asked originally?

Comment: Yeah, and I'm very sorry for that. This was my actual question but wasn't able to form it correctly for the first time.

Comment: See here to properly follow the directory structure - https://bootsity.com/php/create-a-composer-package-and-list-on-packagist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

Yes, you are missing how composer works.

When you run `composer install` command, composer does not move your files from "src" to "vendor", it just simply installs dependencies listed by you in your composer.json under "require" in your "vendor" directory. Since you don't have any dependencies in the composer.json file you posted, there is nothing to install.

> What I want is to make this very project a composer package so that others can install this using composer.

Push the project to github and then add it to [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/submit) using github repository URL. To test that others can use your library, create a new local directory with a composer.json file and in this new composer.json file, under "require", add your library as a dependecy:

```
"require": {
    "bikasv/auth": "*"
}
```

and run `composer install`. Your library should be under "vendor" directory when install process is done.

If this works, the next step is to learn about [package version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions), because you should tag your library how often you can, so other developers can use a specific version of your library, rather then require "*" or "dev-develop".

You can get more familiar with composer by reading [basic usage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) from the docs.

**UPDATE:**

*Regarding your update #2*

From the package you added to packagist, remove from composer.json the line: `"bikas/auth": "*"` (that will mean that your library has itself listed as a dependency).

After you pushed the changed composer.json to github, test it like this:

`$ mkdir -p ~/.tmp/test ; cd $_ && composer require bikas/auth dev-master`

and composer should start installing your library.

Comment: Just because I missed a line here, direct mean you to be rude sir. I know how it works and I'm missing something as I've quite a few packages hosted for my company. Anyway your answer is currently  entirely unhelpful apart from being harsh.

Comment: @BikasVaibhav That was not intended. I'm sorry if you've perceived my post as being rude. See my update in the initial response.

Comment: I'll try that once I go to my PC. Will update afterwards

Comment: Removing that line actually worked. Also, I was using * instead of `dev-master`. It works now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this project to be a dependency of another then the easiest way is to upload it to packagist and require it. The 'requiring' has to be done from your new project and your 'auth' project should then appear in the vendor/bakasv directory. The composer.json in your new project should look something like the example below which I have altered after your edit.

```
{
    "name": "bikasv/someotherproject",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Bikas Vaibhav",
            "email": "******@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Someotherproject\\Namespace": "src/"
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I've no external dependency for this project, hence no require. But shouldn't I get my files copied in vendor folder?

Comment: What files? You haven't declared anything to copy to the vendor folder.

Comment: I think I'm not very clear with my questions. Lemme edit the question, and very sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: The code bikasv/auth in require field was already there for me, which is somehow missing from this code. I've uploaded my code to packagist again http://packagist.org/packages/bikasv/auth

Comment: I tried to install your project, but it fails, because you have this line `"name": "bikasv/someotherproject"` instead of `"name": "bikasv/auth"`. https://github.com/bikasv/auth/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: Are you using this project or just helping me test if it work? If the former, can you help me making it more generic and usable? CUrrently it's just a fork of my exisiting project

Comment: I'm not using it, just helping you test if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't have dependencies in `require` section, so composer only generate autoload files. When you put some libraries to require section then composer will try to install it.